# Installing Maven Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an instruction manual with just the following picture. [image]

I figured it required the following plugin after searching which is a maven plugin. I have already installed maven

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

SO i think I will get the above EAR/WAT settings in my Eclipse->pfreferences after i install this maven plugin. But how do i install a plugin for maven? The above website does not say how to install that plugin. Most searches are leading me to maven eclipse plugin installation instead of this particular installation.

I am installing it for the first time and have not worked with maven before.

Comment: You need to add and configure the plugin in your pom.xml, see the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: You don't install this as a separate plugin rather add the maven-ear-plugin's coordinates (the one which @morgano has mentioned)in your pom file. So whenever you need this maven will automatically download the plugin for you.